# Need whole body tag mouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to whole body mouseover function. When I enter some other page, some of my content will append the particular div.

My code is:

```
$('body').mouseover(function() {
  $('#text').append('<div>New content</div>');
});
```

Comment: This works for me, what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body will not always have its full potential height if the contents fit in a lower height.

You could use `$('html').mouseover` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/mPdd7/.