# mouseLeave is trigged on native input autofil

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, dom-events

I need to show my pop-up when the mouse leaves the `<body>`, this identifies an exit intention.

So when my clients are typing their emails, the popup just appears at the exact moment their pointer is over the suggestion and it should not have happened. But it happens because this part is not in the DOM, so it triggers the mouse leave

however, this event is triggered when the mouse is over a native input suggestion on browsers (I tested on Firefox and Chrome).

So, any ideas how can I skip this **fake trigger**?

```
document.body.onmouseleave = function(e) {
   console.log("mouse leave was trigged")
}
```

**Take a look what is happen**:

[image]

Comment: Set a `mouseLeave` on your input not on your `document.body`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need whole body tag mouseover function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773762/need-whole-body-tag-mouseover-function)

Comment: @KolaCaine, I need to show my pop-up when the mouse leaves the body, showing an exit intent, so when my clients are typing their emails, the popup just appears at the exact moment their the pointer is over the suggestion. it happens because this part isn't in the DOM, So it triggers the mouse leave.

Comment: @FabricioJeanSilva How is it not in the DOM? Did you not tell it to pop up? If you have access to the drop down add am id to it and then set an exception to your function that if it's inside that id then it won't trigger.

Comment: @krizpers the autofill (the drop down) is not in the DOM, it is provided for the Browser, I don't have access to get this, (at least I don't know how), so for the body, it is a mouse leave event.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same issue, solved it by looking at what exactly triggered the mouseleave event. So if it was not an input field from your form, you could proceed and show your popup

```
    $('body').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
        if ('INPUT' !== e.target.nodeName) {
            // do your stuff
        }
    });
```